# How do I find out what Firestore snapshot listeners are still active in my iOS app?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently implementing snapshot listeners in my app, and want to print out a list of active listeners (in my Firebase console I see that I have 2, but it doesn't have any more data than that). Is there a property in my iOS app that I can access or print to find out?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You should record for yourself which listeners are active at any given moment.  You might want to consider writing a wrapper library for yourself to make this easier to apply to your entire app.

Comment: I see. So if I didn't store them in UserDefaults, and no longer have access to those listener instances (only saved them in memory and have since killed the app), is there a way to kill them?

Comment: They are stopped when the app process stops and do not restart when the app is launched again.

Comment: Gotcha, so then what exactly does "Active connections" refer to in the screenshot above? Based on your comment, that should be 0 when I kill the app process, no?

Comment: It doesn't update instantly.  It's a running average intended to help you understand the usage patterns of your app in production.